# Core Data - Possible to sort TableView using blocks in NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: iphone, nsfetchedresultscontroller, objective-c-blocks, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to sort a table by an author's last name. Currently, the data is saved as a string in core data as "FirstName LastName."

I understand that custom selectors in core data are out of the scope of Cocoa and return an `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: compareToLastName:'` Is this true for using a comparator as well?

Here is what I am working from that seems to ignore the comparator completely.

```
// Sort the request
NSSortDescriptor *sortByType;
if ([sort isEqualToString:@"author"]) {
    NSComparator comparisonBlock = ^(id obj1,id obj2) {
        NSString *obj1B = [[(NSString *)obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
        NSString *obj2B = [[(NSString *)obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
        return (NSComparisonResult) [obj1B compare: obj2B];
    };
    sortByType = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sort ascending:YES comparator:comparisonBlock];
}
else {
    sortByType = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sort ascending:YES];
}

NSSortDescriptor *secondSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByType, secondSort, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is even true for `NSComparator` since the sort descriptors are compiled and executed in SQL itself for performance reasons it isn't really supported.

You can read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11 under `Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors`.